# How to install pandas on virtual machine?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to install pandas on oracle VM (which has python 2.7.6, Ubuntu 14.04), but I am getting error.

When I try

```
pip install pandas
```

I get following error

```
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_modak/pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 235, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I try

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

I get this error

```
Get:62 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python-xlwt all 0.7.5+debian1-1 [83.5 kB]
Get:63 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python-scipy amd64 0.13.3-1build1 [7,862 kB]
Get:64 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python-statsmodels-lib amd64 0.5.0+git13-g8e07d34-1ubuntu2 [63.7 kB]
Get:65 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe python-statsmodels all 0.5.0+git13-g8e07d34-1ubuntu2 [3,362 kB]
Fetched 29.8 MB in 49s (604 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-dev_2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Please help.

Comment: Perhaps this is "cheating," but you could download the latest version of Anaconda, which includes pandas as one of it's modules.

Comment: doesn't this have to do with network access on the VM instead of pandas?

Comment: My VM has only CLI, so I can't install Anaconda on it. Furthermore, I have Anaconda installed on my laptop, I just want pandas to be installed on VM, so that I could use it for other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) and use [virtual environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment).